How should we dispose old pictures of devatas and holy books?
In my house we have collected many pictures of deities and gurus, as well as holy books and shloka books. These have become old and dirty over the years. What is the proper way to dispose of them without committing sin?
Thank you

The mud vigrahas can be immersed in sacred rivers. The plastic contents shouldn't be put in the river. Paper ones can be burnt

@Bingming So paper and plastic can be burnt?

I don't know the proper way to dispose plastic because it's a new thing after all w.r.t to our tradition, but don't burn plastic. I guess maybe you may just have to throw it away in garbage. Don't buy plastic mūrtis in the first place, so that you don't have such problem

@Bingming Ok. In addition to paper pictures, can I also burn old holy books that are old and dirty and no longer used? This includes books that contain shlokas and mantras.

I am not sure if it's proper to burn paper pictures, but I think that's a better method than immersing it in the river. After all, offering the paper picture to Agni doesn't seem aśubha, but that must be done respectfully, not like you throw it in your stove or some bonfire.

Old books can be donated to mandiras, libraries, etc. You don't need to burn them, after all they can be read by someone else as well.

@Bingming Ok. Is there any mantra I should recite while burning these? Also it depends on whether the temples accept old books. They may not, especially if the books are damaged and beyond use, because it will also be a burden on them with extra storage.

What did you really do with the books? It seems like you almost destroyed them. Normally, old books, even if it's binding, etc. is damaged, you can put tape, etc. and they can be reused without problem. As for burning paper pictures, I don't know any specific mantra. Maybe just do namaskāra to the devatā whose picture is burnt and then offer them to Agni with namaskāra to him.

I personally wouldn't recommend disposing published scriptures through a junk dealer (the one who takes newspapers, etc. for disposal). Giving him normal books and copies for disposal is alright though.

Missing pages, torn pages, binding gone, etc. I doubt mandirs would take these since it becomes a burden on them and they'd need storage, unless it's like a rare and highly prized piece of writing. I could try though. But nowadays with electronics and everyone having a smartphone, the preferred way of reading is through digital.

I am surprised someone has spoiled the books (that too scriptures) to such an extent. Seems like there was no maintenance of them, and they were just kept lying around without any care. Even when they were read, no one took care to handle them carefully.
